# Counting the number of nodes under a node using hierarchies modelled in neo4j

Tags: php, neo4j, graph-databases

I have a adjacency list (parent/child relationship) modelled into neo4j but counting number of node under the parent gives wrong count.

Here is the cypher query being used

```
MATCH (me:Members)-[:IS_PARENT_OF*]->(child)
WHERE me.membershipID = {membershipID}
RETURN count(child)
```

Comment: does the count from the query is higher ?

Comment: Could you show your graph please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logisima's answer is a great answer and an efficient way to traverse the subgraph. The reason you are getting what I presume is too many nodes in your result though is that you are likely double counting the some children returned in the result.

If you add a `DISTINCT` I think you will return the number you expect.

```
MATCH (me:Members)-[:IS_PARENT_OF*]->(child)
WHERE me.membershipID = {membershipID}
RETURN count(DISTINCT child)
```

You could identify children that are being double counted by doing something like this

```
MATCH (me:Members)-[:IS_PARENT_OF*]->(child)
WHERE me.membershipID = {membershipID}
RETURN child, count(*)
```

Do you have any extraneous `IS_PARENT_OF` relationships in the subgraph in question?

Answer (score 1):

To do this, the best way is to make a graph traversal.
Thanks to `APOC` (https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedure), it's directly possible in cypher.

This query should give you the expected result :

```
MATCH (me:Members { membershipID:$membershipID}) WITH me
CALL apoc.path.subgraphAll(me, {relationshipFilter:'IS_PARENT_OF>', uniqueness: 'NODE_GLOBAL'}) YIELD nodes
RETURN size(nodes)
```